# C++ How to specialize a template using vector<T>?

Tags: c++, grammar, traits, template-meta-programming

Basicly ,I want to make a function behave differently for a vector(type) parameter and a non-vector type parameter .

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename type>
struct is_vector {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename type>
struct is_vector<vector<type>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
template <typename type>
type read()
{
    if (is_vector<type>::value)
    {       
        type vec(10);
        vec.front()=1;//left of '.front' must have class/struct/union   
        return vec;
    }
    else
    {
        return{};
    }
}
int main()
{
    auto i= read<int>();
}
```

I want to return a vector while using vector as the typename ,return an int while using int as the typename .

But since is_vector(int)::value returns false ,why would my compiler reports "left of '.front' must have class/struct/union" ?How can I make it work ?

What I want to achieve is to correctly deserialize a string to a vector(type) or a vector(vector(type)) .

I need to recursively call the read function ,while passing a multidemonsional vector as a template parameter ,but the compiler forbids me to do it .

```
template <typename type>
struct is_vector {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename type>
struct is_vector<vector<type>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename type>
type read(char*& str)
{
    if (is_vector<type>::value)
    {       
        type vec(read<uint8_t>(str));
        for (auto& e : vec)
            e = read<type::value_type>(str);
        return vec;
    }
    return *reinterpret_cast<type*>((str += sizeof(type)) - sizeof(type));
}
```

So I tried specialization .

```
template<>
vector<int> read<vector<int>>(char*& str)
{
    vector<int> vec(read<uint8_t>(str));
    for (auto& e : vec)
        e = read<int>(str);
    return vec;
}//works 

template <typename type>
template <>
vector<type> read<vector<type>>(char*& str)
{
    vector<type> vec(read<uint8_t>(str));
    for (auto& e : vec)
        e = read<type>(str);
    return vec;
}//don't work
```

Do I really need to manually rewrite my read function for every kind of types I use ?

(like vector(vector(vector(int)))?)

Comment: Your check for a vector is a *run-time* check. All the code in that branch still has to be compilable.

Comment: First: The `is_vector` predicate is evaluated at compile-time. Using it in an if indicats that you didn't completely understood what templates should be used for.

Comment: @Albjenow I don't know much about metaprogramming, how can I make my function generate different codes for vector and pod types ?

Comment: As a possible solution to your problem you might want to *specialize* the `read` function: One generic non-vector variant, and one for `std::vector`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you .In a non-vector variant ,I only use one typename ,in a vector variant ,I need to specialize vector and use a T as it's value_type ,so that's two typename ,how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a function template `foo<R>` that is parameterized at least
by return type `R`, and you want a specialized implementation
when `R` = `std::vector<U>`, for arbitrary type `U`.

It doesn't matter what the arguments of `foo<R>` may be, so for illustration
we'll assume there aren't any. Here's how you do that:

Define a *trait* template as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_vector
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<template<typename...> class C, typename U>
struct is_vector<C<U>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = 
        std::is_same<C<U>,std::vector<U>>::value;
};
```

With this,

```
is_vector<T>::value
```

will be true at compiletime if and only if `T` = `std::vector<U>`, for some `U`.

Then define two overloads of `foo<R>()` on the following lines:

```
template <typename R>
std::enable_if_t<!is_vector<R>::value,R> foo()
{
    // Your non-vector implementation instead of...
    std::cout << 
        "In non-vector specialization of `foo<R>()`\n";
    return R();
}

template <typename R>
std::enable_if_t<is_vector<R>::value,R> foo()
{
    // Your vector implementation instead of...
    std::cout << 
        "In vector specialization of `foo<R>()`\n";
    return R();
}
```

These two overloads are mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive. The
first overload pans out to be legal code if and only if `is_vector<R>::value` is false. The
second overload pans out to be legal code if and only if `is_vector<R>::value` is true.
That's thanks to the behaviour of [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if),
which you should study and understand.

When the compiler needs to pick one these template overloads to implement some
call `foo<type>()` that it finds in your code, it discovers that exactly one of the overloads
won't even compile when `type` is plugged in for the template parameter `R`. The first one won't compile if
`type` is some `std::vector<U>` and the second one won't compile if `type` is *not* some
`std::vector<U>`. Helpfully, the compiler picks the one that it can compile.
That's called [`SFINAE` ("Substitution Failure Is Not An Error")](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae),
and it's the solution of your problem.

Here's an illustrative program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct is_vector
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<template<typename...> class C, typename U>
struct is_vector<C<U>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = 
        std::is_same<C<U>,std::vector<U>>::value;
};

template <typename R>
std::enable_if_t<!is_vector<R>::value,R> foo()
{
    // Your non-vector implementation instead of...
    std::cout << 
        "In non-vector specialization of `foo<R>()`\n";
    return R();
}

template <typename R>
std::enable_if_t<is_vector<R>::value,R> foo()
{
    // Your vector implementation instead of...
    std::cout << 
        "In vector specialization of `foo<R>()`\n";
    return R();
}

int main()
{
    auto i = foo<int>();
    (void)i;
    auto vc = foo<std::vector<char>>();
    (void)vc;
    return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
In non-vector specialization of `foo<R>()`
In vector specialization of `foo<R>()`
```

(gcc 6.1/clang 3.8, `-std=c++14` [see live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7aafedf618855f2))